# Second-order sections from complex coefficients

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, approximation, biquad

I have an impulse response ir that I need to approximate with an iir because of realtime requirements. For stability I want to break down the 10th order IIR generated with Steiglitz-Mcbride to biquads / second-order sections. However, I can't use tf2sos with the complex transfer function that stmcb() generates like the following:

```
[b,a] = stmcb(ir,10,10);
[sos,g] = tf2sos(real(b),real(a));
```

When I compare bode plots of

```
freqz(b,a)
```

and

```
freqz(sos)
```

I find that the contour is preserved but there is a large difference in magnitude and phase. Am I missing some scaling factor or limitation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand why `a` and `b` are complex-valued. They shouldn't be I guess. Is `ir` complex-valued? Could you post the coefficients `a` and `b`, and maybe link to the desired `ir`?

Comment: Could it be that your function generates pole/zero locations instead of coefficients? Those would be expected to be complex-valued. Digital filters with complex coefficients are somewhat rare (although they are used in some applications). I've never seen an IIR filter implemented with complex coefficients.

Comment: @JasonR: That's a good idea, but according to [this](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/stmcb.html) it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @MattL.: Thanks for the correction. I wasn't aware that the function was a standard one in MATLAB. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The IR is in fact complex. Taking the real portion shifts the phase by 360 degrees. The bode plot magnitude of the complex IR. I can't post b,a, and the IR but I can tell you they are complex. The phase requirements are critical for this application.

Comment: What are you trying to model by a complex impulse response? And a phase shift of 360 degrees doesn't do anything to a signal. You should probably add more details to your question because I think there's some basic misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: The goal is to model a transfer function that is derived from measured transfer functions with an IIR filter. There is no particular reason it is complex other than that is what I get out of an ifft of the measured transfer function. Maybe I can just use the real part of the ifft as the modeled IR?

Comment: is your complex $h[n]$ something you get from IFFTing an $H[k]$ that is approaching 0 for the latter half of $k$?  that might explain something.

Comment: Your impulse response is complex for the wrong reason. The *frequency response* is complex, but not the corresponding impulse response. The problem is in the way you applied the IFFT to your measured data. If you measured a frequency response, you could directly design a filter approximating that frequency response.

Comment: The IFFT is applied to FFT'd data, specifically ifft(FFT(Y)/FFT(X)).

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued then the result must be real-valued as well, apart from small numerical errors. If $X$ and $Y$ are not real-valued, then the question is what their meaning is.

Comment: Y and X are real valued but their FFT is not

Comment: X is the input flat spectrum sequence and Y is the recorded response of the system under test.